# Error: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am new to Android development.

I got above error when I tried to run sample code - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/

I cleaned and rebuild the project too, then the error goes away but when i try to run again (to run in emulator), then error reoccurs. Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410140/android-studio-java-exe-is-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297062/gradle-build-failed-java-exe-is-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2

Comment: can you compile any Java program with the above mentioned Java version(1.7.0_79)?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: This type of question already asked

Comment: Yes, I saw many similar threats, but could not solve my issue

Comment: one of the solution was to use: defaultConfig {

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
} but I am not sure - where to insert?? sorry to ask a naive question

Comment: Priyank, I am able to, just that when I try to run in emulator - error occurs again

Comment: compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }  - This also does not work

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' also did not help

Comment: You can post your build.gradle

Comment: It is working now. Thanks IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue. I just upgraded the jdk version from `jdk1.7.0_79` to `jdk1.8.0_91` and then added to path. Then the Build and Launch was successful.